# Is there a way to automatically remove unused CSS rules when building a Visual Studio project?

Tags: css, .net, visual-studio

CSS-libraries like [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) and [jQuery UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) are used in my current project. It's obvious that most of the rules from these libraries aren't used, so I was wondering is there a way, using some tool, to remove unused rules from the final CSS bundle when I'm making a release build using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

This article [here](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/remove-unused-css) on KeyCDN seems to have a lot of great options

I'll quickly mention here from that article that you can see for yourself in Chrome Dev Tools which rules are not being applied:

1. Open Chrome Dev Tools, and go to the Sources tab
2. Open the command menu
3. Type in “Coverage” and click on the “Show Coverage” option
4. Select a CSS file from the Coverage tab which will open the file up in the Sources tab

Any CSS that is next to a solid green line means that the code was executed. Solid red means it did not execute. A line of code that is both red and green, means that only some code on that line executed.

Comment: Should the removing of red lines be done manually? Or is there a way to automatically do it in Developer Tools?